# Java, Program reading in a file, output is symbols

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I've been trying to read in a file and it's throwing out symbols. I think its the wrong encoding but I have tried different types of encoding without any progress. The code is below as well as the output. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
InputStream HostFile = new FileInputStream(location + FileName); 
Reader file = new InputStreamReader(HostFile, "UTF8");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(".\\Files\\TempFPF.txt", "UTF8");

while (file.ready()) {
     writer.print((char) file.read());
}
writer.close();
```

Output:

```
坕⁕ㄸ⼸㤰䴠剁䴯䕋匭义倠条⁥റഊ嬊传偆崠਍ⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭ਍坕さㄸ‸†㤰䅍㉒㄰‹†䬠䭍ⵅ南卓†䈠㠷‹㝎㤸塅†䕒䕌十⁅㔱㤳〠䴸剁㤱਍䙏⁐‱††䕇⁎䥍䍔䕈䱌䤠呎ⵌ䡃乁䥇...
```

Comment: Can you provide your input file?

Comment: The input file is a flight plan. Its 500 lines so ill throw in a few lines.

UWU 818/09 MAR/MKE-SIN Page 1

[ OFP ]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
UWU0818   09MAR2019    KMKE-WSSS   B789 N789EX  RELEASE 1539 08MAR19
OFP 1     GEN MITCHELL INTL-CHANGI
                     WX PROG 0912 0915 0918 0921 1000 1003 1006 1009
                         OBS 0806 0806 0806 0806 0806 0806 0806 0806
  ATC C/S   UWU818       KMKE/MKE   WSSS/SIN      CRZ SYS     CI 160

Comment: But that is all ASCII the way I see it here.  Is that true...the file is plain ASCII? - I don't think that can be, as then you wouldn't be getting special characters in the output no matter what you were doing.

Comment: I've attempted to read the file in the ASCII format without any luck. Notepad++ reports it as a UTF-8 file encoding.

Comment: I don't recommend you reading character by  character if the original file is utf8 encoded because because the character is more than one byte length. When you write it to the new file, by default will convert the one byte length character to utf8 and the final file will be bigger in size and different. If your original file is text then read by line otherwise by byte. Please refer to this links for different options. You can read a whole file in a single read if you want to. https://www.journaldev.com/867/java-read-text-file

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you wrote `"UTF8"` when instead it should be `"UTF-8"` (notice the dash). You can also use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();` from `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`

Comment: The output is still the same even with the StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() and adding the dash in UTF-8

Comment: Can you upload the file somewhere so we can see if there's somethign wrong with it?

Comment: Yep file is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15sZt4EPkaBScklgPw8L6UzVaWZdElJOZ
I feel like I'm not getting the full picture of what the code is doing.

Comment: Using your supplied code and your supplied file, the code works for me and I don't get any weird characters. There needs to be something else that's wrong here

Comment: Strange. I'll keep digging and see what i find

Comment: When I run the debugger it actually doesn't "Catch" on a breakpoint inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue I was calling the wrong method that engaged a different file buffer reader that reads files in UTF-16LE. Thank you, everybody, for the help.